# Problem in proof of theorem involving $\lim \sup$ and $\lim \inf$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

Source: Elementary Analysis By Kenneth A. Ross

> Theorem: If $s_n$ converges to a positive real number $s$ and $(t_n)$ is any sequence, then
> $$\lim \sup s_nt_n = s\cdot\lim \sup t_n$$

> Proof: We first show
> $$\lim \sup s_nt_n \ge s \cdot \lim \sup t_n \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \text{(1)}$$
> Let $\beta = \lim \sup t_n$
> (Not writing case 1)
> Case 2: Suppose $\beta = +\infty$
> There exists a subsequence $t_{n_k}$ of $t_n$ such that $\lim_{k \rightarrow\infty}t_{n_k} = +\infty$.
> Since $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}s_{n_k} = s > 0$, it follows that $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}s_{n_k}t_{n_k} = + \infty$. Hence $\lim \sup s_nt_n = +\infty$, so (1) clearly holds.

I have two questions here - 
$1.$ How did the last line reach the conclusion that $\lim \sup s_nt_n = +\infty$? 
$2.$ In the inequality (1), both LHS and RHS are infinity. How are we comparing two infinities with an inequality?